# React Native flexbox not working with minHeight

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

My screen is split into a top and bottom section with styles:

```
<SafeAreaView>
  <View style={styles.top}>
    <Image source={img} style={styles.img}/>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.bottom}></View>
</SafeAreaView>

top: {
  flex: 1
},
img: {
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%',
  resizeMode: 'contain',
},
bottom: {
  flex: 2,
  minHeight: 450
}
```

However, when I do this the bottom half takes up much more space than 2/3 of the screen and I don't understand what may be causing this. When I remove the minHeight everything works as intended other than the fact that I'm missing the minHeight.

If I understand everything correctly the top section should take up 1/3 and the bottom take 2/3? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your styles are stepping on each other. Take care when mixing flexbox with static styling - the results are often not what you want.

Try removing `width` and `height` from the `img` style and adding `flex: 1`.  Also remove `minHeight` from `bottom`.  Your two views should take up 1/3 and 2/3 of their parent view.  You may want to set `minHeight` to a percentage of your screen height instead?  I'm not sure what makes sense for your design.

I found this blog post helpful: https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/understanding-flex-in-react-native-b34dfb4b16d1